# Integration of $\cos x\cdot\cos 2x\cdot\cos 3x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I study maths as a hobby and am trying to integrate
$\,\cos x\cdot \cos 2x\cdot \cos 3x\,$.

I am trying to split this up into a form in which I can integrate each component part. I have tried using the rule
$$2\cos A \cos B = \cos(A + B) + \cos (A - B)$$
but I can only get this far:
$$\begin{align}
\int\cos (x) \cos (2x)\cos (3x)\, dx
 & = \int\frac{1}{2}(2\cos (x)\cos (3x)\cos (2x), dx \\
 & = \int\frac{1}{2}( \cos (4x) + \cos (2x))\cos (2x), dx
\end{align}$$
but from here on I get stuck.

Comment: Shouldn't you have $\cos 4x+\cos 2x$? Then apply the same formula twice.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited accordingly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the formula twice.

$\begin{align}\cos (x)\cos (2x) \cos(3x) &= \frac12(\cos (4x) + \cos (2x)) \cos (2x) \\&= \frac12\cos(4x)\cos(2x) + \frac12 \cos(2x)\cos(2x) \\&= \frac 14 (\cos(6x) + \cos(2x)) + \frac14(\cos(4x)+1)\end{align}$

Comment: You're as the light :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the complex definition of $\cos x =\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$:
\begin{align*}
\frac 18\int &(e^{ix}+e^{-ix} )(e^{2ix} +e^{-2ix})(e^{3ix} +e^{-3ix} ) \mathrm dx  \\ 
&= \frac 18 \int (e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}+e^{ix} +e^{-ix} )(e^{3ix} +e^{-3ix} ) \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac 18\int (e^{6ix} +1+1+e^{-6ix}+e^{4ix}+e^{-2ix}+e^{2ix}+e^{-4ix} ) \mathrm dx \\ 
&= \frac 14 \int \left(\frac{e^{6ix} +e^{-6ix}}{2} + \frac{e^{4ix} +e^{-4ix}}{2} +\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{2} +1\right)\mathrm dx \\ 
&= \frac 14 \int (\cos 6x +\cos 4x +\cos 2x +1)\mathrm dx \\ 
&=\frac 14 \left( \frac{\sin 6x}{6} +\frac{\sin4x}{4} +\frac{\sin 2x}{2}+x \right) + C
\end{align*}

Comment: I’m afraid my text book hasn’t got as far as e yet so this approach is closed to me.

Comment: @Steblo That’s okay. This might be useful to other people.